# how to post a character per line

Tags: python

The assignment is we have to write a program that displays the first 10 digits of pi. Each number should be displayed one per line, without any period in the end. I understand the whole import statement, but I am having lots of errors with the for loop.

Comment: Please share you code and the errors so we can take a look at it and help you!

Comment: convert it to a string. Then iterate through the string `print` each character. Print will insert the newlines. One way is `for c in str(math.pi)[:10]: print(c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Ecuadorian_Programmer. You can control the position of decimals if you convert your number into a string. For example:

```
import numpy as np # For take pi

a = str(np.pi) # We transform the number into a string   

print(a.replace('.','')) # We delete the point decimal separator)
```

> '3141592653589793'

If you want to print in separated lines 10 digits of pi this works fine:

```
import numpy as np # For take pi

a = str(np.pi).replace('.','') # We transform the number into a string without the point decimal separator

for i in range(10):
    print(a[i]) # Print all numbers in separated lines
```

And, if you want to print only decimals (and not the initial 3), you can redefine the variable making:

```
a=a.replace(a[0],'')

print(a) # Only decimals
```

> '1415926558979'

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `print` method, calling it for each digit in pi. Consider the following code:

```py
from math import pi

strPiDigits = str(pi).replace(".", "")

for i in range(10):
    print strPiDigits[i]
```